# How to allow (but not require) specific words in specific places using regex?

Tags: regex, validation, matrix, expression

I have this regex validation expression (thanks to ClasG and Marvel308): See Link for examples.

[^((?P\begin{(?\w+)}\s*(?:-?\d+\s*(?:&\s*|\\n))+\end{\g})|\$\s*(?P>matrix)\s*\$|\$\$\s*(?P>matrix)\s*\$\$|[\s*(?P>matrix)\s*]|(\s*(?P>matrix)\s*))$](https://regex101.com/r/Cq9QDX/5)

At the beginning of each row that contain the -?\d's (numbers) I would like to allow (but not require) the word "\left(". And at the end of each row that contain the -?\d's I would like to allow (but not require) the word "\right)" How can I edit this validation expression to satisfy this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should do:

`^((?P<matrix>\\begin{(?<token>\w+)}\s*\n(?:(?:\\left\()?\s*-?\d+\s*(?:&\s*|\\\\\s*(?:\\right\))?\n))+\\end{\g<token>})|\$\s*(?P>matrix)\s*\$|\$\$\s*(?P>matrix)\s*\$\$|\\\[\s*(?P>matrix)\s*\\\]|\\\(\s*(?P>matrix)\s*\\\))$`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Cq9QDX/6)

Modifications:

1. Added `\n(?:\\left\()?\s*`, a check for the zero-and-one presence of a non-capturing group for the 'left' part.
2. Added `\s*(?:\\right\))?`, another check for the zero-and-one presence of a non-capturing group for the 'right' part.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited my regex expression to this instead: https://regex101.com/r/Cq9QDX/8

The only problem I have is that the last row of numbers is not supposed to have "\\" at the end. Is there any way satisfying that?

Comment: Nevermind I fixed that too :) I'm catching on quick! Thanks to all of you. I have one more thing I need to change, I will edit my question and I'll let you know when.

Comment: How can I create a group and allow a series of different words permitted? For example, right before I allow a number in my expression I would like to allow (but not require) one or more of the words listed. I'm guessing that it would look similar to the (?:\\right\))? but adding the | (or) in between words?

Comment: Yes. the OR operator `|` is used for this purpose. Give it a try, if you face any problems feel free to ping.

Comment: hey bud I can use your help for one last thing for my regex expression. Let me know when you're online please :) what I have to do is so simple but yet it's driving me nuts trying to fix through trial and error lol

Comment: You can edit the question if it's related, or ask a new one altogether. I am sure someone will be able to answer your queries.

Comment: I'd suggest you ask a new one, since you have already marked this question as resolved. If your query still builds on this question/answer itself, you can refer to it in the new one in order to maintain context.

Comment: writing a new question I'll post you the link when it's up.

Comment: Here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45852655/how-to-make-my-symbol-at-the-end-of-each-row-optional-without-disrupting-my-curr

I hope you can figure this one out!

Answer (score 1):

You can add non-capturing groups quantified with `?`, which allows the groups to match 1 or 0 times:

`(?:\\left\()?`

`(?:\\right\))?`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll let you know if I can put it in the right place :) (I'm relatively new to this.) Also, how can I allow both (?:\\left\()? and (?:\\left[)? is there a short way of doing expressing this?

Comment: Yes, good luck! You could use `[\(\[]`. There's a quick reference on the bottom right of regex101.com, the common tokens are quite useful to remember :)